# Расшифровка POST запроса от Unity3d

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, unity3d

Есть приложение на Unity, которое отправляет POST запрос серверу.

```
public IEnumerator POST()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("variable1", "222");
    var www = new WWW("http://127.0.0.1:8080/server.js", form);
    yield return www;
    Debug.Log(www.text);
    www.Dispose();
    yield break;
}
```

Есть сервер на node.js который его принимает и отсылает обратно инфо о приеме и дату.

```
 function accept(req, res) 
{
   console.log(req);
// через 1.5 секунды ответить сообщением
   setTimeout(function() {
    res.end('Отправляем обратно! ' + new Date() + req.url);
   }, 1500);
}
```

Сообщение отправляется на сервер и обратно, в клиенте мы используем

```
WWW.text
```

Для получения строки ответа от сервера. А что использовать на сервере? Как расшифровать POST запрос от Unity? На данный момент я просто использую

```
console.log(req)
```

И в итоге там вываливается всё. Причем ожидаемых

```
("variable1", "222");
```

Среди этого нет. 
Вот что приходит.

```
IncomingMessage {   _readableState:    ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: true,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },   readable: true,   domain: null,   _events: {},   _eventsCount: 0,   _maxListeners: undefined,   socket:    Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [BufferList],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Array],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::8080',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6 },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::8080',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6 },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false,
        _timer: [Timer] },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false,
        _timer: [Timer] },
     _idleStart: 25381,
     _destroyed: false,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage:
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
        _sent100: false,
        _expect_continue: false,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: null },
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 6 },   connection:    Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [BufferList],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Array],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::8080',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6 },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::8080',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6 },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false,
        _timer: [Timer] },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false,
        _timer: [Timer] },
     _idleStart: 25381,
     _destroyed: false,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage:
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
        _sent100: false,
        _expect_continue: false,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: null },
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 6 },   httpVersionMajor: 1,   httpVersionMinor: 1,   httpVersion: '1.1',   complete: false,   headers:    { host: '127.0.0.1:8080',
     'user-agent': 'UnityPlayer/2017.1.1f1 (UnityWebRequest/1.0, libcurl/7.51.0-DEV)',
     accept: '*/*',
     'accept-encoding': 'identity',
     'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'x-unity-version': '2017.1.1f1',
     'content-length': '152' },   rawHeaders:    [ 'Host',
     '127.0.0.1:8080',
     'User-Agent',
     'UnityPlayer/2017.1.1f1 (UnityWebRequest/1.0, libcurl/7.51.0-DEV)',
     'Accept',
     '*/*',
     'Accept-Encoding',
     'identity',
     'Content-Type',
     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'X-Unity-Version',
     '2017.1.1f1',
     'Content-Length',
     '152' ],   trailers: {},   rawTrailers: [],   upgrade: false,   url: '/server.js',   method: 'POST',   statusCode: null,   statusMessage: null,   client:    Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [BufferList],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Array],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::8080',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6 },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::8080',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6 },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false,
        _timer: [Timer] },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false,
        _timer: [Timer] },
     _idleStart: 25381,
     _destroyed: false,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage:
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
        _sent100: false,
        _expect_continue: false,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: null },
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 6 },   _consuming: false,   _dumped: false }
```

Comment: Рекомендация: в nodejs не используйте `console.log`, настройте нормальный логгер вроде https://github.com/winstonjs/winston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с NodeJS ответ очевиден - JSON. Нужно на стороне Unity закодировать данные по синтаксису JSON, типа

```
 string sss = "{\"f1\":\"val \",\"f2\":12345,...}";
```

Эту строку отправить POST, ну и на стороне Node зделать:

```
 data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Принять данные POST на NodeJS:

```
 var svr = http.createServer(function(req, resp) {
   var body = "";
   req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
   });
  req.on('end', function () {
    console.log('body: ' + body);
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(jsonObj.$key);
  })
});
```

Comment: Благодарю вас, но это, в свою очередь, порождает еще вопрос - как отправить с юнити JSON? 

Отправить одну строку в POST в Юнити нельзя, можно добавить в отправляемую форму только это:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.AddBinaryData.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.AddField.html
Как ввести туда данные, чтобы их мог расшифровать JSON.parse на сервере?

Comment: то я ж написал - отправьте строку sss как аргумент в POST, а потом расшифруете - form.AddField("data",sss); UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(endpoint, form); - ну а в Node берите аргумент data и парсите